# ACTION_DIAL- "content://contacts/people/1 " Doesnt input the first contacts number in the dialer?

Tags: java, android

When I try the Intent -ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/1" it opens the dialer on the device but does not transfer the first contacts number.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);

  Intent intent = new Intent 
 (Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/1"));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ACTION_CALL` and `ACTION_DIAL` do not take a `Uri` of a contact as a value. The `Uri` needs to be a `tel:` `Uri` with the phone number. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#DialPhone).

Comment: I see. But what if I don't know the phone number, and just want it to pull what ever the first contact is? is this possible?

Comment: @LinS: Well, there is no "first contact". There is no requirement for `content://contacts/people/1` to be a valid `Uri`, as there does not have to be a contact with an ID of 1. And, even if there is a contact with an ID of 1, that may not be "first" in any way that the user would measure it (e.g., alphabetically, chronologically). It might just be "first that got added via an import process", which could be a random contact. You might want to use `ACTION_PICK` to let the user pick a contact, then query the `ContactsContract` provider to get the phone number.